# Negative numbers for toBinaryString in Java

Tags: java

The documentation for `Integer.toBinaryString` states that, it returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer. It also goes on to state, that negative numbers are converted to their magnitude in positive form.

Which from what I understand is two's complement of the negative number. However, when I run the following for negative number, I still obtain the string representation of the number in it's signed form, that is it's two's complement.

Am I missing something here?

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(13));  // 1101
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-13)); // 11111111111111111111111111110011
```

Comment: From the Javadoc: "The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2^32 if the argument is negative"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of the javadoc you are viewing. From the [Java 15 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)):

> The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2^32 if the argument is
> negative; otherwise it is equal to the argument. This value is
> converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra
> leading 0s.

That describes exactly the result you got. Unsigned integer value referred to in the doc just means that all values are converted to non-negative values. The value you are converting is -13. The documentation says that for negative numbers, the value is added to 2^32. 2^32 - 13 = 4294967283. In binary that's 11111111111111111111111111110011 so that is the string that is returned.

Comment: Then perhaps there is a gap in my understanding here. From what I seem to be catching on here then is that if the number is negative, then it will return its two complement. Can you explain the documentation a bit, as in what does returning argument as unsigned integer mean here ?

Comment: Sure I'll add the calculation to my answer to make it clear how it's derived. Note that there is no need to understand anything about 'two's complement' - the derivation is simple arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks @sprinter for the example. One last follow up, restating the documentation as that the function returns the signed representation of the provided integer should also be correct, right ?. Since we are accepting int as argument, which is signed, the function is simply returning the signed binary representation of the same.

Comment: @arjunkhera it's important to remember that the Java API is a standard. It tries to avoid defining functions based on implementation details such as how integers might be represented. If the JVM changed in the future to represent integers in a different way (e.g. to take advantage of new processor features) this documentation would ensure that the result of `toBinaryString` wouldn't change.